# Array value binding in WPF

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, xaml

I have an object with an Array of doubles property like this:

```
private double[] _axes;

public double[] Axes
{
    get
    {
        return _axes;
    }
    set
    {
        _axes = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Axes[]");
        }
    }
}
```

This Array is always assigned as a whole, because i get an Array of double out of my database object and set it to the Axes property like this:

```
object.Axes = GetDataRow(i);
```

(this is just to demonstrate that i in fact assign the whole Array)

In my XAML now i bind it like this:

```
 <Label  Content="{Binding Path=Axes[0], UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

I set the DataContext of the window to the Object that has the Axes property and the UI receives one value from it at program start that i assign in the constructor of the object. 
However, even though the "Axes[]" event is raised constantly (which i checked from another object), no further values arrive in the UI.

So my question is: CAN this even work? Does `Axes[]` not correspond to `Axes[0]`? what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The binding system won't look "into" the array for updates. You just need to notify it that the property itself changed. You're currently saying that a property called `Axes[]` changed, but you don't have a property with that name. It's just `Axes`

```
public double[] Axes
{
    get
    {
        return _axes;
    }
    set
    {
        _axes = value;
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Axes");
        }
    }
}
```

If you really need to know if an individual item in the array is changing, then you should be using [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx), which the binding system *does* know how to look "into".

Answer (score 2):

Your property name is incorrect in the notification

```
if (PropertyChanged != null)
{
     NotifyPropertyChanged("Axes");
}
```

Remove the brackets. This should solve your problem in this case. However, it is recommended to use ObservableCollection for binding a list of objects.

Comment: That won't help if he mutates the array

Comment: @Anoobi If it answers your query, do not forget to mark it as the answer.

Comment: @SLaks What does it mean to mutate the array?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose: `Axes[2] = 4;`

Comment: @SLaks agreed. His question explicitly stated he replaces the entire array. Thats why the Array solution

Answer (score 0):

No.

You have no property named `Axes[]`, so that event has no effect.

You should not bind to arrays; instead, use `ObservableCollection`, and make the property read-only.